# Drawing arcs/curved line/arrows with Leaflet using method other than arc.js?

Tags: leaflet

I've been trying to find a good way to draw arcs or even arrows dynamically with Leaflet.js, but I haven't come up with much.

I tried [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/), however I was having problems with that approach, and I do not want to do it that way.

What else can I do to draw arcs in leaflet?

I've looked all over but I'm new to leaflet and can't find anything that would be of help.

Comment: There are a few [Leaflet plugins for drawing arcs and complex shapes](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers) listed that you could try.

Comment: You can try [creating-consistently-curved-lines-on-leaflet](https://medium.com/@ryancatalani/creating-consistently-curved-lines-on-leaflet-b59bc03fa9dc)